# Tabla viajes - Clientes

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla viajes con la siguiente estructura

```
codigo
descrip
codcli1
codcli2
codcli3
```

Otra tabla `clientes` con la siguiente estructura

```
codigo
nombyapellido
dni
direccion
```

Cuando quiero hacer un select de la tabla viajes donde el `cliente1` o el `cliente2` o el `cliente3` sea igual a La Colina SRL

yo haría algo así:

```sql
 Select * 
from viajes a, clientes b 
where ((a.codcli1=b.codigo) or (a.codcli2=b.codigo) 
   or (a.codcli3=b.codigo)) and b.nombyapellido like'%La Colina SRL%' 
order by 1
```

Traería todos los viajes donde `cliente1` o `cliente2` o `cliente3` contenga La Colina SRL.

Estaría bien solucionar así o como sería la forma correcta de solucionar esto????

Comment: Si necesitas que sea igual a un valor, ¿por qué pones que lo contenga? Define la lógica real porque no es lo mismo.

Comment: por que tienes codcli1, codcli2, codcli3?, de hecho podrías tener un rompimiento, una tabla llamada viajes_clientes y ahí reúnes los atributos correspondientes, toma en cuenta las demás recomendaciones. saludos

Comment: Toma en cuenta lo que dice Patricio. Tu tabla no esta bien diseñada.. Que pase si en el viaje van mas de 3 personas?

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la búsqueda tienes que relacionar cada columna con la tabla de clientes:

```
Select * 
       from viajes a
       left join clientes b 
             on a.codcli1 = b.codigo
       left join clientes c 
             on a.codcli2 = c.codigo
       left join clientes d 
             on a.codcli3 = d.codigo
       where b.nombyapellido like'%La Colina SRL%' 
             or c.nombyapellido like'%La Colina SRL%' 
             or d.nombyapellido like'%La Colina SRL%'
       order by 1
```

**Comentario aparte**: Lamentablemente la complejidad de la consulta se debe al diseño que tienes en las tablas. Un diseño normalizado reduce la necesidad de agregar varias veces la tabla de clientes a la consulta mediante una tabla de detalle del tipo `cientes_por_viaje`.

Comment: Creo que podrias evitar los 3 joins si solo haces un in a la tabla clientes. Pero igual, solo vas a complejizar el where. pero casi seguro, va mas rapido...

Comment: Si, es otra posibilidad, buscar clientes con el nombre, recuperar los ids de estos y luego chequear si los tres cliente_id de los viajes están en esta lista.